# Is google datastore projection queries can get all data in an entity?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

According to this documentation [Here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing)

If I use projection queries with all properties in entity.It will cost me 1 entity read for query and small operation for results.

Is it better than I get all key  with key-only queries then get entity data with **get(key)**? It will cost me 1 entity read for query and N times entity read for entity data.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it to simply retrieve all entities, with no filters? It will depend on the amount of properties your entity has, and if you always need to access all of them. You should consider that, to use projections, it is necessary to specify composite indexes, and these incur in storage overhead. If you could update your question with more information about your use case, it will be easier for us to determine what would be the optimal approach.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that getting an entity via query is subject to eventual consistency while key lookups are strongly consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that while projecting will result in a single read op, you need to have all the fields you want to project to be present in the index. An additional index has storage cost and also potentially increase the write latency. So, if you are projecting just a couple of fields of small size, then you can create such a composite index and do a projection and it will only cost one operation.

If composite index with projection is not an option, then you can still try to resolve as much of your where clause as possible via the index and at that point a single query that fetches all the entities will only cost N and (not 1+N where you first get keys and then the entities).

Comment: But won't 1+N be cheaper compared to N? This is basis the recent pricing. Because what I can see from the documentation is that projection queries for fetching limited set of fields compared to all the fields for the same filters will cost less. And once I get all the keys, I just get all fields using the keys which is free. So, resultant cost will still be less.